# Unable to load a file in flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gensim

We have a `flask` application where we need to load a pretrained model located at the path `'/root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin'` using `gensim`. While running the code I am getting below error

```
File "mlapi.py", line 26, in <module>
    e2v_model = ModelEmoji2Vec()
  File "/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/apps2/mlapi/models/susheels/text2emoji/vector_model/modelE2V.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.e2v = gsm.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(emoji2vec_path, binary=True)
  File "/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/vnc_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1498, in load_word2vec_format
    limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
  File "/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/vnc_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 342, in _load_word2vec_format
    with utils.open(fname, 'rb') as fin:
  File "/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/vnc_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 308, in open
    errors=errors,
  File "/home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/vnc_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 517, in _shortcut_open
    return _builtin_open(parsed_uri.uri_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin'
```

Basically, error is occurring at

```
#modelE2V.py, line 19
self.e2v = gsm.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(emoji2vec_path, binary=True)
```

It says that permission denied. But if I try to load the model using simple python script outside flask app it works fine, why this error is occurring inside flask application

Comment: do you run simple script using `sudo`? Why do you have resource in root folder? Why don't you install it in `/home/atinesh` ? Using `root` for anything is not good idea.

Comment: @furas No I am not running simple script with sudo

Comment: I still think it is not good idea to install anything in `/root/`, I would install it `/home/atinesh` or globally (in its default folder)

Comment: I don't know how you run flask but usually web servers works as different user, with different privilages, in different folder and with different environment's variables - all for security. For example web server `Apache` runs all code as uses `www-data` without access to other users (not only `root`) for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a File Permission error. This means the unix user that is attempting to access your file does not have the required permissions to do so.

It appears you are storing your pretrained model file at
`/root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin`

This looks like a location that requires root or sudo privileges to access.
To verify this run

```
ls -l /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin
```

The output will probably be something like:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 6 Dec 29 XX:XX /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin
```

This indicates only the users in the root group can read and write (rw) the file, and that only the root user can read and write the file.

When you preprend `sudo` to a command you are changing to the root user and then executing the rest of the command as this root user. So running the python script with sudo means that the root user will execute the script, because the root user has access to /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin the script will run without a problem.

However when you run flask, you are running it with a different user. On yourt development box (your computer) most likely the unix user running flask is `atinesh`.

So the basic solution is to modify the permissions of /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin to be owned or at least read, by atinesh.

@furas pointed out in the comments that installing resources in /root/, as you have done here, is usually a bad idea, and I agree.

The optimal solution is to:
Relocated your file and change the permissions.

```
mkdir /home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/apps2/mlapi/resources
sudo cp /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin /home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/apps2/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin
sudo chown atinesh:atinesh /home/atinesh/Downloads/Current/vnc_chat/apps2/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin
```

If you are set on not relocating the file you could just change the permissions where it is now:

```
sudo chown atinesh:atinesh /root/apps/mlapi/resources/emoji2vec.bin
```

As an aside, in production environments, it may be wise to create a new unix user called "app" (or something like that) and then only give the user "app" permissions to a single folder that contains your flask code. This prevents your app code from touching files you don't want it to. Also if your flask application was somehow compromised the attacker would only have the permissions of "app" user.